# Confusion about Meteor _uihooks and what triggers them

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm confused about how [`_uihooks`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md#blaze-2) works. Check out the below code:

**home.html**

```html
<template name="homePage">
  <section id="home-page">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Thought of the day:</h1>

      <div id="totd">
        <span>{{thought}}</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

**home.coffee**

```coffee
timer = 0

Template.homePage.rendered = ->
  this.find('#totd')._uihooks =
    insertElement: (node, next) ->
      console.log 'Inserted'
    removeElement: (node) ->
      console.log 'Removed'

  Session.set 'randThought', Random.choice thoughts
  timer = Meteor.setInterval shuffleThoughts, 5000

Template.homePage.destroyed = ->
  Meteor.clearInterval timer

thoughts = [
  "My socks smell like sausages."
  "I sure wish I had a bag of crisps right about now."
  "I need more thoughts."
]

Template.homePage.helpers
  thought: -> Session.get 'randThought'

shuffleThoughts = ->
  Session.set 'randThought', Random.choice thoughts
```

I'd like the random thoughts to fade out/in nicely. But I never see anything show up in the console, so apparently it's not working. What exactly triggers `_uihooks`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see this article for a good run through http://www.webtempest.com/meteorjs-animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach the call `._uihooks` on the *parent* DOM node ( not a JQuery object) of the nodes you want the effects on.  In your case this is `$('div.container').get(0)` in homePage.

You also need to insert or remove a DOM node not just reactively update text inside a node.  This could be done with an `#each` or `#if` in your template.

You will also need to insert and remove the DOM node yourself manually within the hooks.  Otherwise only inserts will be logged and nothing will actually show up on your page.

`_uihooks` are explained [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-core/1kUoG2mcaRw/j4bNvXu36IoJ) with an example [here](https://github.com/percolatestudio/transition-helper/blob/master/transition-helper.js).

I have made [another example with your code working in meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/XeQq2g9PyFhYo5orK/_uihooks).

Comment: Aha! The example I found for `_uihooks` used `this.find('obj')` but what you've done makes more sense. I also knew I had to use `#each` but I thought it would just look through the array and dump out all the thoughts at once. But I see you're returning an array of one object, clever. Thanks for this!

Comment: `this.find('#obj')` returns DOM object - not jQuery object so it is fine here.