# "removed" event in Meteor

Tags: events, meteor

I want to trigger an event when an element is removed from the DOM.

In one of my templates I show a checkbox only when a condition is met:

```
{{#if some.thing}}
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
{{/if}}
```

This checkbox later then is converted to a [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) component.

What it does is, it hides the original checkbox and adds some markup to the document. All OK with that.

Now, if my collection changes and the condition, which previously was met, now evaluates to false, the checkbox is removed from the DOM. The node created from Bootstrap Toggle though stays present. So I want to remove the nde when the checkbox is removed.

I thought I could to this with the `DOMNodeRemoved` event but have some issues there:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  "DOMNodeRemoved input.checkbox": function(el) {
    $(el.currentTarget).bootstrapToggle('destroy');
  }
});
```

The event fires, but somehow it ends in a cascade when I call `bootstrapToggle('destroy')` and the browser freezes. Also the event fires multiple times before and it makes me think this is not the correct way to watch for removed nodes in the first place.

Is there any better way to watch for removed elements and fire an event before they are deleted?

I know I could simply call a helper from my template, manually check if the node exists and delete the node with jQuery. But I'd like to see if this is possible with Meteor.events instead.

Comment: You want _uihooks, probably. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260092/confusion-about-meteor-uihooks-and-what-triggers-them

Comment: Why not put the bootstrap markup directly in your template instead of adding it to the DOM after the fact with jQuery?

Comment: `_uihooks` sounds exactly what I want, yes. Unfortunately I was not able to get it working. No matter if defined as described in the linked question/answer or with `gwendall:ui-hooks` the events never are fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the `input` (and the new bootstrap node/s) inside a child template, this should "just work" out of the box.

```
<template name="parent">
  {{#if some.thing}}
    {{> child}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="child">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <!-- additional bootstrap nodes get instantiated in child -->
</template>
```

In the above, if `some.thing === false` the input and the new node/s will be removed from the DOM by Meteor automatically.

Comment: So simple! Indeed that worked. I had to place a container node around the `input` so the bootstraptoogle node really was added in the template scope. Thanks!